# Why with "array[row][col]= usedspace;" cannot increase specific columns and rows depending on the increse each variable (row or column)?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am Michael and I am new to this forum.
What I want to ask is how through Java Script to make a character 'O' follow your character 'X' in a '.' that is a 20*20 array, but where 'X' pass '.' is replaced with 'O'.
E.g. increase some way the counters inside the if statement that relies in the for loops of row and column of "array a" ?

```js
function start()
{

 document.getElementById("wrapper").style="visibility:hidden";
 
 
 var  optionOne = document.getElementById("optionOne");
 var display = "";
 
 var txt1 = document.getElementById("txt1");
 var mtxt1 = parseInt(txt1.value);
 
 if (mtxt1 == 1)
  {
  display += "<p>Pen is currently NOT DRAWING</p>";
   document.getElementById("wrapper").style="visibility:display";
  
  }
 else if (mtxt1 == 2)
  {
  display += "<p>Pen is  DRAWING</p>";
  document.getElementById("wrapper").style="visibility:display";
  }
 optionOne.innerHTML = display;
 
 
  var button = document.getElementById("getbutton");
  button.addEventListener("click",start,false );
  
  
  //var displaygmb = document.getElementById("displaygmb");
  //displaygmb.addEventListener("click", displaygameboard("Gameboard",array,length,arraydisplay),false );
  
  var button2 = document.getElementById("get2button");
  button2.addEventListener("click",option2(button2,mtxt1),false );

  
}



function option2(buttonn,symbolinput)
{
 
  var input = symbolinput; 
  var usedspace = "O";
  var turtle = "X";
  var gameboardSymbol = ".";
  
  var clickcountt = buttonn;
  var count6 = 1;
  var count5 = 1;
  var count3 = 1;
  var count4 = 1;
  var display = "";
  clickcountt.onclick = function() {
    
 
 var optiontwo = document.getElementById("optiontwo");
 var display2 = "";
 
 var txt2 = document.getElementById("txt2");
 var mtxt2 = parseInt(txt2.value);
 
 
  if (mtxt2 == 6)
  {
   count6 += 1;
   display2 += "<p>Turtle is moving "+count6+" places down</p>";
  }
  else if (mtxt2 == 5)
  {
   count6 -=1;
   count5 +=1;
   display2 += "<p>Turtle is moving "+count6+" places up</p>";
  }
  else if (mtxt2 == 3)
  {
   count3 += 1;
   display2 += "<p>Turtle is moving "+count3+" places to the right</p>";
  }
  else if (mtxt2 == 4)
  {
   count3 -=1
   count4 += 1;
   display2 += "<p>Turtle is moving "+count3+" places to the left</p>";
  }
  
  optiontwo.innerHTML = display2;
  
  

   var gameboardsize = 20;
   var  arraydisplay = document.getElementById("arraydisplay");
   
   
   var array = new Array (gameboardsize);
      var length = array.length;
      for (var i = 0; i <= length; i++ )
   {
    array[i] = new Array(gameboardsize);
   }
      
   var  arraydisplay = document.getElementById("arraydisplay");
      
      var displaygbd = "<table id=gameb align=center><thead><th>"+"Gameboard"+"</th></thead><tbody>";
   
   
    for (var row = 1; row <= length;  row++)
  {
    //three += 1;
    displaygbd += "<tr>";
  for (var col = 1; col <= length;  col++)
  {
   
   
   if (input == 1){
   //four += 1;
   if (((row ==count6)&&(col ==count3))) 
    {
    array[row][col]= turtle;
    }
   else {
    array[row][col]=gameboardSymbol;
   }
   }
   //----------------------------
   else if(input == 2)
   {
   
    
   if (((row == count6)&&(col ==count3)))
   {
   array[row][col]= turtle;
   
   }
      /*how to make 'O' follow 'X' by ibncrease the appropriate counter in the if below?*/
   else if (((row <= count6)&&(col <=count3)))
    {
    array[row][col]= usedspace;
    }

    
    
   else  if ((((row >= count6)||(col >= count3))))
   {
   array[row][col]=gameboardSymbol;
   }
   
   }//end else if 
     
   //----------------------------
   
   displaygbd += "<th>"+array[row][col]+"\xa0"+"</th>";
  }
  displaygbd += "</tr>";
  }
   displaygbd += "</tbody></table>";
      
   
   arraydisplay.innerHTML = displaygbd;
      
      
  }//end clickout function     
  
}





window.addEventListener("load",start,false);
```

```css
@charset "ISO-8859-1";

#customers {
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 30%;
}
#customers td, #customers th {
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    padding: 8px;
    
}

#customers thead th {
    padding-top: 12px;
    padding-bottom: 12px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
}

#customers tbody th {
    padding-top: 12px;
    padding-bottom: 12px;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Initializing an array</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"> 
<script src ="tutle.js"></script>
</head>
<body>


select your first option
<input id ="txt1" type="text">
<input id = "getbutton" type ="button"  value = "your option">
<div id = "optionOne"></div>

<br/>


<div id = "arraydisplay"></div>

<div id="wrapper" >
select your second option
<input id ="txt2" type="text">
<input id = "get2button" type ="button"   value = "your option">
<div id = "optiontwo"></div>
</div>

<div id = "counters"></div>
<div id = "optionthree"></div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you add a concrete example to explain your question?

Comment: we have a 'textbox: "var mtxt2;" ' and a button("var clickcountt = buttonn;") 
and we create a function "clickcountt.onclick = function() {}". 
before this function we have declare four counters (var posx= 1;var posy= 1; var posz = 1;var post = 1;). 
Inside this function  and depending the input in 'mtxt2' the appropriate counter is increased and decreased as well
e.g. if  (mtxt2= 6) then posx +=1; if (mtxt2= 3) then posy +=1; but if (mtxt2= 5) then posx -=1; and the same goes for mtxt2 =4
i.e. posy -=1;.

Comment: I have uploaded my code on git as i don't know how to upload code here. https://github.com/Mickeyxs91/turtlegraphics

Comment: I saw your code. Could you explain further, what do you want to do in it? Currently, it generates a table with an 'X'. Tr to keep it simple.

Comment: if the first option in "txt1" is 2 then the 'X' is moving in the 20*20 array of '.' with the help of the counters that simulate the clicks of  button2 e.g. if the txt2 is 6 then posx +=1 if txt2=3 then posy+=1; but if txt2 = 5 then posx-=1; or txt2 = 4 then posy -=1; with the view to move the 'X' to the opposite direction.

Comment: What I am trying to do is to include 'O' in 20*20 array of '.' and make it to follow 'X' when posx and posy are increased  but now the character 'O' replaces all the characters of '.' in the 'X''s pass in the particular row or column. How to I make such thing. Hope to describe it thoroughly.

Comment: in  a few words 'O' follows 'X' and replaces all the '.' behind it in each row and each column from the column that the counter posy was increased or the row  that the counter posx was increased

Comment: So, is it like the 'snake game'? We provide a new position of 'X' and the path from old to new position should be filled with 'O'. Only the new position will have 'X'. Or we do not want to paint the whole path with 'O's. Just the positions.

Comment: `if the first option in "txt1" is 2 then the 'X'....` This comment is super confusing and wrong i think :|

Comment: Ok my wrong "if the first option in txt1 is 2 then the 'X' " I mean that in the case that we use 2 in the first text box then we can pass the control to another if statement that performs the appropriate replacement.

Comment: What I am understanding is that you provide the value to increment the position of 'X'. But when we move X to it's new location, O should take its place. Are we getting close?

Comment: sorry my mistake again I add a 'readme.js' in https://github.com/Mickeyxs91/turtlegraphics  which I hope to illustrate the problem as clear as I could

Comment: Oh. I'll try to update with an answer later.

Comment: Does the solution help?

Answer (score 0):

Sharing a possible solution. 
This should get you more than started.

Try running this here itself and let me know if this is ok. I'll add an explanation if required.

The 2 inputs receive the new location of 'X'. `text1` receives row number and `text2` receives column number. On button press, the corresponding dimension is updated.

```js
var button1 = document.getElementById('getbutton');
var button2 = document.getElementById('get2button');
var textbox1 = document.getElementById('txt1');
var textbox2 = document.getElementById('txt2');
var gridX = 20;//table size length wise
var gridY = 20;//table size width wise
var arrayContainer = document.getElementById('arraydisplay');
var currentX = 1;//initial positions
var currentY = 1;

function init() {
 var myTable = document.createElement('table');
 myTable.setAttribute("id", "customers");
 arrayContainer.appendChild(myTable);
 //Creating initial grid
 for(var i=0; i<gridX; i++) {
  var row = document.createElement('tr');
  for(var j=0; j<gridY; j++) {
   var text = document.createTextNode('.');
   var column = document.createElement('td');
   column.appendChild(text);
   row.appendChild(column);
  }
  myTable.appendChild(row);
 }
 //Setting initial value
 document.getElementsByTagName('tr')[currentX-1].getElementsByTagName('td')[currentY-1].innerText = 'X';
}

init();

button1.onclick = clicked;
function clicked() {//1st position changed
 var newX = parseInt(textbox1.value);
  var newY = parseInt(textbox2.value);
 moveTo(newX, newY);
}

button2.onclick = clicked;


function moveTo(newX, newY) {
 //Setting old value to 'O'
  var char = 'O'
  if(newX == 1)
    char = '.';
 document.getElementsByTagName('tr')[currentX-1].getElementsByTagName('td')[currentY-1].innerText = char;
 //Setting new location with 'X'
 document.getElementsByTagName('tr')[newX-1].getElementsByTagName('td')[newY-1].innerText = 'X';
 //Updating current location of 'X' for future use.
 currentX = newX;
 currentY = newY;
}
```

```css
@charset "ISO-8859-1";

#customers {
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 30%;
}
#customers td, #customers th {
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    padding: 8px;
    
}

#customers thead th {
    padding-top: 12px;
    padding-bottom: 12px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
}

#customers tbody th {
    padding-top: 12px;
    padding-bottom: 12px;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Initializing an array</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"> 
<!-- <script src ="turtle.js"></script> -->
</head>
<body>



select your first option
<input id ="txt1" type="text">
<input id = "getbutton" type ="button"  value = "your option">
<div id = "optionOne"></div>


<div id="wrapper" >
select your second option
<input id ="txt2" type="text">
<input id = "get2button" type ="button"   value = "your option">
<div id = "optiontwo"></div>
</div>

<div id = "counters"></div>
<div id = "optionthree"></div>
<br>
<div id = "arraydisplay"></div>




</body>
<script src ="turtle.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: First of all I want to thank you for your interest, this answer is close to the solution but, the desired output is to increase only the column that 'X' is.  if 'X' has made a its journey from [1][1] to [1][5] and then move down then the desired column that needs to be increased is column number 5 up to the level that we change again the destination e.g.if we stop at [11][5] and go forward with 3 then desired row that needs to be increased is row number 11.

Comment: Hard to understand that. If you want to prevent the position of 'X' from going left, you can add a check for it in the `onclick() method`. Byt the way, why are there 2 buttons? Also, are the text inputs for 'x' and 'y' coordinates right?

Comment: The first button call the start function that checks if mtxt1 is 1 or 2 and the second button calls the option2 function that includes button2 and the input of mtxt1. No i don't want to prevent 'X' from going left I want 'X' to be free to move left right up down while its particular row or column that 'X' is moving are replaced from a 'O'.

Comment: if mtxt1 is 1then the character 'O' is not included in the 20*20 array and we only move the character 'X' in it.......if mtxt1 is 2 then we move the character 'X' in the array of '.' but now we include character 'O' in the positions that character 'X' passed

Comment: Right now the 'O' is replacing old positions of 'X'.

Comment: Try now. Modified. Now both the buttons trigger the same function. Also, '.' replaces old position in case of a '1' inside mtxt1.

Comment: Thanks a lot the last edit gave me motivation that a possible solution exists for that problem, but the '.' is replaced with 'O' through the input of 1 through 20 regarding rows and the same goes for columns e.g. the row or the column is changed regarding the input provided in each textbox. I am going to see how to modify it with the view to move 'X' through the input of 3 (right),4 (left), 5 (up), 6 (down).Thanks a lot by the way

Comment: Happy to help! Hopefully, now you can edit this to your requirements.